# Angular Conditional from Mock Array Object

Tags: arrays, angular, if-statement

I'm not sure how to get an array object and pass it into a conditional (if I am stating this wrong, feel free to edit the title and question :).

This is what I am attempting; See `calculateClasses()` below:

**In the component:**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; import { AIRFRAMES } from './mock-airframe-list'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-airframe-list',
  templateUrl: './airframe-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./airframe-list.component.scss']
}}

export class AirframeListComponent implements OnInit {

  fabIcon = 'plus';
  fabLink = '/inventory/add-airframe';

  airframes = AIRFRAMES;

     calculateClasses() {
       if(airframe.airframeStatus === 'airworthy') {
         return {
           'green': true
       } else if (...){. . .};
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**In the mock-airframe-list Data:**

```js
import { Airframe } from '@app/modules/inventory/airframes/pages/airframe-list/airframe';

export const AIRFRAMES: Airframe[] = [
  {
    airframeStatus: 'airworthy'
  },
  {
    airframeStatus: 'maintenance'
  },
  {
    airframeStatus: 'unairworthy'
  },
];
```

**In the airframe class:**

```js
export class Airframe {
  airframeName: string;
  airframeModel: string;
  airframeHours: number;
  airframeFlights: number;
  airframeType: string;
  airframeSN: string;
  airframeStatus: string;
}
```

**...and the**

```html
<button
  mat-mini-fab
  [ngClass]="calculateClasses()" >
  <fa-icon
    icon="plane-departure"
    class="airframe-card-fab-icon" >
  </fa-icon>
</button>
```

Any help to educate me here is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please try this one in if if(this.airframe.airframeStatus === 'airworthy') {..}

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand your question. What are you trying to achieve. You have an array of airframes. Now what? If you want to calculate the CSS classes that **one** airframe should have, then you need to pass the airframe as argument to the method.

Comment: So `airframe` is an Array and you are trying to accessing a prop from it? You should be rather doing it from its index. like: `airframe[index].airframeStatus`. If you would also mention your intention behind your code we can provide more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
calculateClasses(airframe) {
  return {
    'airplane': true,
    'green': airframe.airframeStatus === 'airworthy',
    'yellow: airframe.airframeStatus === 'maintenance',
    'red': airframe.airframeStatus === 'unairworthy'
  }
}
```

I think you are making it more difficult than it needs to be. The [ngClass] directive already evaluates the object passed into it based on the thruthiness of the expression. So make sure you are passing the object from the array into the method, so it has access to the properties you want to check like below.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let frame of airframes">
  <button
    mat-mini-fab
    [ngClass]="calculateClasses(frame)" >
    <fa-icon
      icon="plane-departure"
      class="airframe-card-fab-icon" >
    </fa-icon>
  </button>
</ng-container>
```

The end result would be something like, first airframe in your array would return a classlist of "airplane green", the second would be "airplane yellow" and finally "airplane red".

Comment: Your absolutely right! I was over thinking it. Not too often I see someone who can actually read the code and understand whats being asked.

Answer (score 0):

An even more simpler way is:

```html
    <ng-container *ngFor="let airframe of airframes">
      . . .
      <button
        mat-mini-fab
        [ngClass]="{
          'green': airframe.airframeStatus === 'airworthy',
          'yellow': airframe.airframeStatus === 'maintenance',
          'red': airframe.airframeStatus === 'unairworthy'
        }" >
        <fa-icon
          icon="plane-departure"
          class="airframe-card-fab-icon" >
        </fa-icon>
      </button>
      . . .
    <ng-container>
```